# Issue with checking files on Android

Tags: java, android, file, io, exists

I use File f = new File(s) to create a new file from the press of a button, and it saves the file. The 'saved' files are then collected using .fileList() / getApplicationContext().fileList() (both work) and are used in a for loop to save to an ArrayList, which then gets passed to a ListAdapter for a ListView. In the adapter I set a button to delete each file. I placed Logs on each section of the code and when I press a button, the individual buttons and files are recognised, but at f.exists() it always returns null. Even when the list is created using collected files, so the files must be there, it always returns null. Why is this? I've been trying to debug for 3 days now!

code from the adapter to delete (everything else in the adapter works):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
        File f = new File(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());
        if (f.getAbsoluteFile().exists()) {
            f.delete();
            Log.d("delete", f.getAbsolutePath().toString() + " is deleted!");
        } else {
            Log.d("delete", f.getAbsolutePath().toString() + ": doesn't exist?");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Edit:
Tried to delete all files in data directory (ones created by = new File(s))

```
String [] filenames = getApplicationContext().fileList();
if (filenames.length > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++) {
        File f = new File(filenames[i]);
        Log.d("file selected:", f.getName());
        Log.d("file path:", f.getAbsolutePath().toString());
        if (f.exists()) {
            if (f.delete()) {
                Log.d("deleted:", f.getName());
            } else {
                Log.d("couldn't delete:", f.getName());
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("doesn't exist:", f.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Makes this in stack trace: (+10 others)

```
12-16 21:31:11.187: D/file selected:(1270): new_recipe
12-16 21:31:11.187: D/file path:(1270): /new_recipe
12-16 21:31:11.187: D/doesn't exist:(1270): new_recipe
12-16 21:31:11.197: D/file selected:(1270): Untitled_Recipe
12-16 21:31:11.197: D/file path:(1270): /Untitled_Recipe
12-16 21:31:11.197: D/doesn't exist:(1270): Untitled_Recipe
12-16 21:31:11.197: D/file selected:(1270): hgk
12-16 21:31:11.197: D/file path:(1270): /hgk
12-16 21:31:11.197: D/doesn't exist:(1270): hgk
```

AAARGH!

Comment: Post your `Adapter` code

Comment: posted. fyi the filename/listview name, basically each file name is static throughout the app

Comment: Try adding some logging and see what getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString() produces, is it the correct file path?

Comment: I've updated the post and created a wealth of logging. Could it be my emulators? I've tried on all 4 of them!!

Comment: Where are the files located? Does /new_recipe mean you delete files from the root dir? Did you check on the device (or in the emulator) that the files exist in the place you think they exist?

Comment: They are located in the default data directory achieved by File = new File(). new_recipe is just a name of a file. I am only using that method to make the files so they should exist all in the same place. I think I'll delete everything and start again because none of this is making sense

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason of this behaviour is, that `File` is just wrapper around path `String` and returns information on demand, like `exists()`. So when you create new `File` with name "not existing", getName() etc. will still work.

**Nothing is really created on file system when you call new File("fileName")**,

only object in memory and then you can call file.createNewFile() to create empty file on specified location.

If you are getting files via `getApplicationContext().fileList()` these files are in your application private storage and there were created with `getApplicationContext().openFileOutput("fileName", mode)`, their real path is `/data/data/<your package name>/files/<filename>.`For these file no `File` object is needed. to create, modify or delete. Everything should be handle through `Context` and file name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, deleteFile() doesn't work for me, I've placed the file names into a String array then taken the name from the array and called the method with it but it isn't wanting to. Do I need special permissions?

Comment: No you do not need any permission because via listFiles() you access only your private storage. Check edit.

Comment: Great! Yes I figured out that File just makes an instance of a file. Now I use open file input and create file, using file and object input streams to write data. Much thanks!